# skimage.external.TiffWriter: naming importance

Tags: python, tiff, scikit-image

I need to save images as a .tif. I cannot install a new python package (university-controlled computer, with Anaconda), so I decide to use the available Tifffile present in skimage.external.

Here is the trouble:
The following code works nice and saves the 3 channels of my image:

```
from skimage.external.tifffile import TiffWriter
import numpy as np
path = '26.01.2021 NLFK CPV timeseries A3B10 imaged 07.04.2021/26.01.2021 NLFK CPV timeseries A3B10 imaged 07.04.2021/Processed'
result_img2 = np.zeros((3, 512, 512))
res = (6.006634765625e-08, 6.006634765625e-08)
raw_b = str('abcdefg')
meta = {}
for i, c in enumerate(result_img2): 
    with TiffWriter(path+'/'+'test_C'+str(i)+'.tif') as tif:
        tif.save(np.array(c, dtype='uint8'), resolution=res, description=raw_b, metadata=meta)
```

But I just cannot keep my images named 'test'!
However, doing like this:

```
filename = "07.04.2021 NLFK nucleolin r488 A3B10 m546 DAPI mock Preview 2_nucleus1_"
with TiffWriter(path+'/'+filename+str(i)+'.tif') as tif:
    tif.save(np.array(c, dtype='uint8'), resolution=res, description=raw_b, metadata=meta)
```

Results in an `Errno 2` error.

I tried to check if this filename contains forbidden characters (from another post):

```
keepcharacters = (' ','.','_')
filename = "".join(c for c in filename if c.isalnum() or c in keepcharacters).rstrip()
```

or the encoding `filename.encode('utf8')` and it also failed (again, `Errno 2`).

The name indicates the condition of each experiment and changes every time, so I need to save it like that.
After a quick check, I can save it at the root of the .py. But again, I need the file to be saved in their respective folder.
Any idea of where my trouble can be?

Comment: Does `open(path+'/'+filename+str(i)+'.tif', 'wb')` work? You might be running into the maximum path length limitation (248 bytes for directories, 260 bytes for directory+filename). If that is the case, ask your sysadmin to enable long paths on Windows 10.

Comment: @cgohlke I think I was afraid of this. But you are right, `open` also gives me the `Errno 2` error. I will reduce the path length since my users cannot have the long path enable... Thanks for your comment!